# How to associate angular web client to Hyperledger fabric identity

Tags: angular, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm just wondering how to associate a certain IP address (i.e. the IP address of my angular web app 0.0.0.0:4200) to a certain participant in my blockchain network.

I have a number of identities in my wallet in my rest server - but I don't know how to associate these identities to an actual client URL. Is this the right way of thinking and if so does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your use case (actionable or merely reference) is but you seem to want to have a registry entry, linking a client URL with an identity in Composer?

You could create a simple Participant Registry that keeps the identity name (as issued by Composer) and the client URL you provide - thats associated with this particular business network.

eg

```
"$class": "org.acme.network.MyAssociatedIds", "Id": "joe1",  "data_elements": "'dmainip://myclientURL:5000/app/someurl' }
```

or similar.

Comment: Yes, Paul, I want an actionable reference so that when the participant logs into his web app they can only carry out the operations that their respective identity is entitled to in the network. Is there any documentation on how to do this?

Comment: so if participant 'joe' logins into the web app, he will have a business network card (including his certificate/key) associated with him - and is subject to ACLs through the mapped participant in Composer.. We don't have documentation on your specific use case (i'm sorry) and obviously you would need to manage the client URLs you describe - you could always control this on the client side, against what the ACL rules currently define (as ultimately if these change, given different  business network editions,  it may restrict/grant more/less client URLs operations that your web app must observe